# Sonos getMetadata request 100+ items

Tags: soap, sonos

I've been developing a music Service for Sonos and have everything up and running. The problem I have is Sonos only requests 99 items through it's getMetadata call, some of my libraries have 300+ tracks in, so I'd ideally like to list them all out.

I can't find anything in the Sonos api documentation about how to list 100 or more items but I'm assuming it is possible because their reference page for getScrollIndices (http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/103) alludes to a library much larger than 100 tracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default number of items requested in a `getMetadata` call by setting the `BrowseOptions.PageSize` value to something more appropriate for your service in a presentationmap.xml file.

E.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Presentation>
   <!-- I chose 400 based on your 300+ value in the question. -->
   <BrowseOptions PageSize="400" />
</Presentation>
```

You can find documentation at the link below. Scroll down to 'Browse Options':

http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/222

And you can find documentation on how to configure Sonos to read your Presentation Map during local testing here:

http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/134

In essence, you need to host the XML file on a server (often the same server that hosts your Sonos API code), and configure the URL in the customSD form that points directly to the presentationmap.xml file.

Note: Sonos caches the XML file for performance. When you change the file, you must increment the version in the customSD form so Sonos controllers force a reload. This is explained in the 'Version' entry in the documentation here:

http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/134